# editing errors messages in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

im currently trying to edit the error messages in magento 1.9.0.1 checkout that says "The onepage checkout is disabled". Ive tried going into app > locale > en_US and edit the text in that csv file but no luck on the website.

Any ideas? - Attached an image of the message I want to change below

[image: I have attached an image below of the message i want to change]

Comment: Did you clear cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the magento template path hints, go to that path and edit it.

Check the following link http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento